# How to save user's location in database

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to save Google maps data into MySQL DB ? using php . I am currently working on a code where when  users enter my website, system will get their latitude and longitude automatically. I use Google maps API, but I don't know how to save latitude and longitude in my database. Please help in transferring these values for server side in php and adding them in database Thanx very much :^)

Comment: You're going to have to make an ajax call to a script on your server to add the data to your database. You should really try something before asking here though. Come back when you have an issue with your code ;)

Comment: You don't need Google Maps API to get users geolocation. Check navigator.geolocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example, using `navigator.geolocation` and jQuery to pass the information to your backend (AJAX).

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'your_backend_page.php',
            data: {
                'lat': position.coords.latitude,
                'lng': position.coords.longitude
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                // If your backend page sends something back
                alert(result);
            }
        });

        // Use the 2 lines below to center your map on user location (you need a map instance at this point)
        userLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map.panTo(userLoc);
    });
}
```

In your PHP page, you will receive the data as `$_POST['lat']` and `$_POST['lng']` and you can use them to insert the data in your MySQL database.